# Acumatica Customize Business Logic Scan Screens

Tags: acumatica, barcode-scanner, production

I would like to customize AM302020 screen. I need to change the scan process. The need is to save the data in the first time with the beginning date/time of the production order, by clicking on a new customized button "start" after scanning the differents fields (ordertype, production order id,...). Then clicking on a new customized button "end" will save the end date/time of the production order and calculate the labor time.
How could be the different steps to develop this functionality?

Comment: https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/